# Ubuntu T14 AMD crashes periodically

Tags: kernel, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

My Ubuntu T14 AMD periodically crashes.

journalctl logs:

```
$ journalctl -b -1 -e
Dec 12 17:44:01 myt14 wpa_supplicant[795]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-38 noise=9999 txrate=866700
Dec 12 17:46:18 myt14 systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\M019.Y9**], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: 
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [M019]
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: 
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [M019]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel:   Arg0:   000000009ead7c10 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel:   Arg1:   0000000047405888 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel:   Arg2:   000000005c85a8d0 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000005
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel:   Arg3:   00000000c3a5f713 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: 
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \M019 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \M276 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.AZAL._PS0 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/pspars>
Dec 12 17:54:12 myt14 kernel: acpi device:1d: Failed to change power state to D0
```

System info:

```
~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
~ $ uname -a
Linux myt14 5.11.0-051100-generic #202102142330 SMP Sun Feb 14 23:33:21 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You have a custom kernel. Try an Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: I had to install a 5.11 kernel so that Ubuntu works with the AMD processor. The kernel that came installed (5.8) wasn't compatible.

Comment: Now 20.04.3 has a 5.11 kernel.

Comment: Should I just update to the latest kernel 5.15 or is 20.04.3 only compatible with certain kernel versions? I already have 20.04.3 running with kernel 5.11.0 that I installed using the https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh script.

Comment: First try the normal Ubuntu 5.11.0-41-generic kernel. It should be installed and selectable in grub menu.

Comment: I tried `5.11.0-43-generic` and observed the same. The PC restarted after running for several days (through sleep, hibernation etc.). I see the same error before the crash: `kernel: acpi device:1d: Failed to change power state to D0`